# Why is my Facebook app not getting the allow access box?

Tags: facebook, canvas

```
 $app_id = "someid";

 $canvas_page = "http://mydomain/index.php/fbresponse";

 $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

 if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
        //echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
        echo "NO USERID";
 } else {
        echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
 }
```

I always get NO USERID.  I am at apps.facebook.com/myapp and it is set up for an app iframe.  I just never get the allow access box to popup for the user. It just goes straight to no userid.  At least one time this worked.  Now it always goes to no userid.  Thanks.

Comment: uncomment the line before `echo "NO USERID";`

Comment: I did that.  I'm back where I was.  It goes to the website instead of staying in the iframe.  I need a break.  thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get an undefined index for signed_request in my facebook app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7534241/why-do-i-get-an-undefined-index-for-signed-request-in-my-facebook-app)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is probably working, but you have agreed to the permission box before. The access box only pops up once per app. There are some exceptions, for example if you try to request extra permissions or you request permissions that the user decided to skip in the past. That would explain why you said that at least one time this worked.

I suggest setting up a test user and seeing if the permissions dialog pops up for that user. You can do this through your app dashboard - by going to "Roles", "Test Users"